# Sort divs by value

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am trying to sort articles by a child div inside using js.

My article html using Expression Engine looks like this:

```
<article class="panel panel-default leaderBoard races hidden-xs">
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 hidden-xs col-xs-3">
        <div class="stat"><span>{count}</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        <h3><a href="{site_url}/drivers/home/{screen_name}">{first_name} {last_name}</a></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <div class="profilePic"><a href="{site_url}/drivers/home/{screen_name}"><img src="{profile_image:Square}" alt="{title}" class="img-circle driver img-responsive" width="100" height="100" /></a></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        {relationship}
            {if '{relationship:results_grid:total_rows search:session="Race" sort="desc"}' >= 10 && '{relationship:results_grid:total_rows search:session="Race" sort="desc"}' <= 24}
            <div class="badgeHolder img-responsive" style=" background: url('/images/badges/100/bronze.png') no-repeat;" class="badgeSmall img-responsive">
                <div class="totalRows">{relationship:results_grid:total_rows search:session="Race" sort="desc"}</div>
            </div>
            {if:elseif '{relationship:results_grid:total_rows search:session="Race"}' >= 25 && '{relationship:results_grid:total_rows search:session="Race"}' <= 49}
            <div class="badgeHolder img-responsive" style=" background: url('/images/badges/100/silver.png') no-repeat;"  class="badgeSmall img-responsive">
                <div class="totalRows">{relationship:results_grid:total_rows search:session="Race" sort="desc"}</div>
            </div>
            {if:elseif '{relationship:results_grid:total_rows search:session="Race"}' >= 50}
            <div class="badgeHolder img-responsive" style="background: url('/images/badges/100/gold.png') no-repeat;" class="badgeSmall img-responsive">
                <div class="totalRows">{relationship:results_grid:total_rows search:session="Race" sort="desc"}</div>
            </div>
            {if:else}
            <div class="badgeHolder img-responsive" style="background: url('/images/badges/100/locked.png') no-repeat;"  class="badgeSmall img-responsive">
                <div class="totalRows">{relationship:results_grid:total_rows search:session="Race" sort="desc"}</div>
            </div>
            {/if}
        {/relationship}
    </div>
</div>
```

I basically want to sort the articles by div.totalRows descending. I have so far only managed to return the values, but i'm not sure what to do next.

Heres what I have so far:

```
var badgeRaces = document.getElementById('races').getElementsByClassName("totalRows");

function badgeRacesCount(i){
   for(var i = 0; i < badgeRaces.length; i++){
     return badgeRaces[i].innerHTML;
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.